Открытие файла с помощью .bat, когда путь к папке изменяется
Есть рабочая папка с программой, которую приходится часто подкидывать на рабочие станции клиентов.
Там находится исполняемая программа, которая создает перезаписываемый файл.
Путь к папке на станции клиента может быть разным.
Мне нужен батник для открытия файла внутри моей папки, где бы она не находилась.
Использую Notepad++.
Батник, Notepad++ и создаваемый файл всегда будут находиться в одной папке, только путь к папке будет разный.
Данная команда работает пока путь не изменится:
start notepad++ "D:\A\sp12\12.txt"


bat @echo off start notepad++ "%~dp012.txt" сработает, если у клиента не установлен notepad++?

Чтобы создать батник, который будет открывать файл  12.txt  в Notepad++,  независимо от того, где находится папка, вы можете использовать переменную  %~dp0.
Эта переменная возвращает путь к директории, в которой находится сам батник.
Вот пример содержимого вашего батника:
@echo off
start notepad++ "%~dp012.txt"


UPD:
(команда start с дополнительными параметрами)
@echo off
start "" "C:\Path\To\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%~dp012.txt"


В команде start первый параметр — это заголовок окна.
Если вы не хотите устанавливать заголовок, вы можете оставить его пустым, указав "".
Второй параметр — это путь к вашему исполняемому файлу Notepad++
C:\Path\To\Notepad++\notepad++.exe замените на актуальный путь.


я не автор. Все получилось

bat
@echo off
start notepad++ "%~dp012.txt"
сработает, если у клиента не установлен notepad++?

@НиколайКудряшов Нет, не сработает. Один вопрос — один ответ. Я могу дать код, как обработать этот сценарий, но уже в ответе к другому вопросу. Смело задавайте новый вопрос! ;)
